# finalizers cause portability issues - how?

Tags: java, finalizer

Effective Java item 7 says, finalizers cause portability issues.

> Finalizers are unpredictable, often dangerous, and generally unnecessary.
>   Their use can cause erratic behavior, poor performance, and portability problems.

But I could not understand Java being platform independent how finalizer can cause portability issues?

Comment: You may need to read [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=7)

Answer (score 4):

Finalizers usually contain code which releases non-JVM (system) resources. If resource management is entrusted to them, they create very unusual resource lifecycle patterns (a huge number of needlessly open resources + releasing thousands of resources at once). This does indeed sound dangerous and on each yet-untested platform it poses a threat of breaking unpredictably.

Comment: For instance, maybe you test your code on a system that allows 20,000 open files at a time and has relatively little memory (and thus more frequent GC and thus finalization), but your customer is on a system that only allows 10,000 open files at a time and has more memory (so less GC, files closed less often). In that case, things will work fine in your test env but will fail at your customer's site (due to file handles being used up).